# How to get direction in UIPanGesture and increase/decrease or scale view accordingly

Tags: iphone, xcode, gesture, pinch

As I am new to this field.
I searched a lot over net but cant find anything relevant.
I am trying for `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` where once the user Pinch horizontally view should scale only horizontally, similarly for vertical also and if user does it diagonally it should scale in both directions.
Currently my view is scaling in both direction as I am doing

```
CGAffineTransform newTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(currentTransform, scale, scale);

[[(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender view] setTransform:newTransform];
```

Please help me on same.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subclass [UIGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) an implement:

```
– touchesBegan:withEvent:
– touchesMoved:withEvent:
– touchesEnded:withEvent:
– touchesCancelled:withEvent:
```

In these delegates to your custom code for touch gesture.